# Ionic 2/3 :Dynamically set RootPage

Tags: ionic2

I have a scenario where I have 2 profiles (user and admin) and I have a selection page once a person logs in. On the selection page, there are 2 radio buttons for (User and Admin profiles), what I am trying to achieve is, the person can choose only 1 profile (this is achieved by the radio button), now assuming I have saved the selected value, I want to set the rootPage to AdminPage or UserPage, but I don't want to immediately navigate, I just want to update/set the path so that when the person goes back (by pressing the back key or previous button) it will take the person to the desired page. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Do you have any code to share of what you've tried? Is this selection page your root page?

Comment: I am actually still developing this piece of functionality. And I got stuck midway, hence the question :)

Comment: @GabrielBarreto, it's not the root page.

Comment: Ok, i think i got a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maby this will put you in the right direction:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#insert

do not set adminPage or userPage as rootPage but insert the page on the stack

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that you want to set the root to a new page after the user tries to go back, the easiest way to achieve this is using the `NavController` [navguards](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController) to execute a code before leaving the page, this way it'll check wich page the user has selected and then set the root.

Since the select can be easy impemented following [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/) i'll leave that aside. Let's just say you have a property `userType` that is a string and can be 'user' or 'admin', in your select page you'll do the following:

```
public canLeave: boolean = false; //this'll controll if the user can leave the page or not
public userType: string = 'user'; // just setting a default value to your select

// this is a navguard
ionViewCanLeave() {
  if(!this.canLeave){
    if(this.userType == 'user'){
      this.canLeave = true; // you'll need to set canLeave to true so when setting the rootpage it doesn't enters the if statemente again
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('UserPage');
    } else {
      this.canLeave = true;
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('AdminPage');
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: somehow it's not setting the root page. the method fires up (ionViewCanLeave()) but the this.navCtrl.setRoot doesn't set the page.

Comment: @Arun- oh, sry i did it wrong but i have edited my answer. You'll need a property to controll if you can leave the page or not, after calling setRoot it calls ionViewCanLeave again, so i was creating an infinite loop. Try this way and let me know if it worked

Comment: @Gabirel, it's not working. :( still the same behaviour, in fact I get an error which says Invalid Link

Comment: Can you show your full error? Are you calling your page correctly? You need to see if you've lazy loaded your application or if you need to import the page to set the root

Comment: core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: UserPage
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:322)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:310)
    at nav-controller-base.js:365
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:4128)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3

Comment: I also noticed that my rootPage is set to UserPage, tthen I navigate to selection page where I give users an option to choose UserPage or AdminPage

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to the error,

```
    ionViewCanLeave() {
  if(!this.canLeave){
    if(this.userType == 'user'){
      this.canLeave = true; // you'll need to set canLeave to true so when setting the rootpage it doesn't enters the if statemente again
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('UserPage'); // <-- this should be UserPage instead of 'UserPage'
    } else {
      this.canLeave = true;
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('AdminPage'); // <-- this should be AdminPage instead of 'AdminPage'
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```